# Consequence of Brun's Sieve

Tags: number-theory, sieve-theory, twin-primes

I'm following a text that uses Brun's sieve (as described in [https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cdx/Sieve.pdf](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ecdx/Sieve.pdf) in Theorem 2.2.2) to prove the following theorem:
For any $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z},\alpha\neq0$, we have
$$\#\{p\le x: |p+\alpha|\text{ is prime}\}<\frac{cx}{(\log x)^2}\prod_{p|\alpha}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}$$ for some absolute positive constant $c$.

They then use the set $A:=\{n+\alpha: n\le x\}$, $P$ is the set of all primes and $\omega(2)=1$ and $\omega(p)=2$, $p>2$. For this, I have 2 questions:

1. They don't show that the hypotheses of Brun's Sieve are satisfied. I've figured out the first 2 hypotheses, but the last one is giving me trouble. How do we know that $|R_d|\le \omega(d)$ for any square free $d$? (where $R_d = |A_d| - \frac{\omega(d)}{d}|A|$)
2. Further in the proof, we have the following:
   $$\prod_{p<z}\left(1-\frac{\omega(p)}{p}\right) = \prod_{\substack{p<z\\p|\alpha}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\prod_{\substack{p<z\\p\not|\alpha}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)=\prod_{\substack{p<z\\p|\alpha}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{p}\right)^{-1}\prod_{\substack{p<z}}\left(1-\frac{2}{p}\right)\le \frac{c_1}{(\log z)^2}\prod_{p|\alpha}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}$$
   The only thing that I'm stuck on here is the inequality at the end. I know I should be using Merten's Theorem here, but I'm not sure how to get the value that's shown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### EDIT

I've figured out my second problem, thanks to [Theorem precedding Schnirelmann's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742852/theorem-precedding-schnirelmanns-theorem?rq=1), however, I'm still not sure about my first problem. Any help would still be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For practical purposes, one only needs to care about the case where $\alpha$ is even, which indicates that

$$
n+\alpha\equiv0\pmod p\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
\text{1 solution} & p=2 \\
\text{2 solutions} & p>2
\end{cases}\Rightarrow\omega(p)\text{ solutions}.
$$

By the Chinese remainder theorem, we know for sure that $n+\alpha\equiv0\pmod d$ has $\omega(d)$ solutions whenever $d$ is squarefree. If we were to divide the range $[1,x]$ into intervals of size $d$. Then

$$
\left||A_d|-\omega(d)\left\lfloor\frac xd\right\rfloor\right|\le\omega(d).
$$

Because $|y-\lfloor y\rfloor|\le1$, we see immediately that

$$
|R_d|=\left||A_d|-{\omega(d)\over d}x\right|\le2\omega(d),
$$

which still satisfies the conditions for Brun's sieve (In fact, $|R_d|\le L\omega(d)$ for any fixed $L>0$ will work).