# The number of $n$ and $n+2$ that have at most seven prime factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory, twin-primes

In Murty and Cojocaru, we have the theorem: As $x\rightarrow\infty$,
$$\#\{n\le x: n \text{ and } n+2 \text{ have at most seven prime factors}\}\gg \frac{x}{(\log x)^2}$$
The proof uses Brun's sieve with $A:=\{n(n+2): n\le x\}$ $P$ being the set of primes, and $\omega(2) = 1$, $\omega(p)=2$, so that if $S(A,P,z)$ is the number of elements in $A$ not divisible by any $p<z$, then
$$S(A,P,z)>\frac{1}{2}x\prod_{2<p<z}\left(1-\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(1-F(\lambda)\right) + O(z^{G(\lambda)})$$
for specific functions $F$ and $G$ that are unimportant here. The book then picks an appropriate $\lambda$ such that $F(\lambda) > 1 + O(1/\log z)$ and $G(z) < 8$. Then the book says this implies $$S(A,P,z) \gg \frac{x}{\log^2x} + O(z^\theta)$$ with $\theta < 8$

1. My first question is how do we get this? I can only get $$S(A,P,z)\gg \frac{x}{\log x}\prod_{2<p<z}\left(1-\frac{2}{p}\right) + O(z^\theta)$$
   I imagine it has something to do with Merten's Theorem, but I'm not sure.

The book then continues to say that if we choose $z:=x^{1/u}$ with $u<8$, we get the result.

2. I'm not able to draw the connection between $S(A,P,x^{1/u})$ and $\#\{n\le x: n \text{ and } n+2 \text{ have at most seven prime factors}\}$. Does anyone have insight as to why this implication is true?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For (2), note that any integer up to $x$ without prime factors below $x^{1/8}$ can't have more than $7$ prime factors. For (1), you're right about the connection to Mertens's theorem (note that $(1-\frac2p) > (1-\frac1p)^2$. Are you sure you've correctly recorded the inequality concerning $F(\lambda)$? That would result in an extra power of $\log x$ in the denominator that isn't wanted, and (given just that inequality alone) $1-F(\lambda)$ might even be negative.

Comment: @GregMartin Just saw your comment. He recorded the inequality for $F(\lambda)$ wrong, the term is actually $F(\lambda) = G(\lambda)H(\lambda)$, $G(\lambda) = \frac{2\lambda^2 e^{2\lambda}}{1 - \lambda^2 e^{2 + 2\lambda}}, H(\lambda) = \exp\left(\frac{4c_1}{\lambda \log z}\right)$. The author then observes that as $z \to \infty$ $H(\lambda) > 1 + O(1 / \log z)$, but chooses $\lambda$ such that $G(\lambda) < 1$. Seems that OP simply got the details wrong. Also, I think $\prod 1 - \frac{2}{p} < \prod 1 - \frac{1}{p}$ as shown in my answer should just work, squaring will just give a low order term

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for pointing that out, I did record the inequality wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, by Merten's we have $\prod_{2 < p < z} \left(1 - \frac{2}{p}\right) \geq \prod_{2 < p < z} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)^2 \gg \left(\frac{1}{\log z}\right)^2$. Then following the book's calculation,

$$
S(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{P}, z) \gg \frac{x}{\log^2 z}\left(1 - F(\lambda)G(\lambda, z)\right) + O\left(z^{1 + \frac{2.01}{e^{\lambda} - 1}}\right)
$$

Where $F(\lambda) = \frac{2\lambda^2 e^{2\lambda}}{1 - \lambda^2 e^{2 + 2\lambda}}$ and $G(\lambda, z) = \exp\left(\frac{4c_1}{\lambda \log z}\right)$. Now, note that as $z \to \infty$, $G(\lambda, z) \ll 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{\log z}\right)$. Also, letting $\lambda' = \lambda e^{\lambda}$ we see that $F'(\lambda') = \frac{2\lambda'^2}{1 - e^2\lambda'^2}$, and we can find that $\lambda' < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 + e^2}}$ will give us $F'(\lambda') < 1$. This corresponds to $\lambda < W\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2 + e^2}}\right) = 0.2533\ldots$. With this constant, $1 + \frac{2.01}{e^{\lambda} - 1} = 7.97\ldots < 8$. Picking $z = x^{1 / (\theta + \epsilon)} < x^{1 / 8}$ and combining everything gives

$$
S(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{P}, z) \gg \frac{x}{\log^2 z}\left(1 - F(\lambda)\left(1 + \frac{1}{\log z}\right)\right) + O(z^{\theta}) \gg \frac{x}{\log^2 x}
$$

2. By definition, $S(A, \mathcal{P}, z)$ is the number of $n \leq x$ such that $p < z \implies p \not \mid n(n + 2) \implies (p \not \mid n \, \land p \not \mid n + 2)$. If we write out the factorization of $n = p_1p_2 \cdots p_k$, we note that $p_i \geq z$, so $n \geq z^k = x^{k / u}$. Since $n \leq x$, $k < u < 8$ and $n$ has at most seven prime factors. Same for $n + 2$.

Hope this helps! I am studying sieve theory as well :)

Comment: The inequality on $\prod_{2<p<z} (1-\frac2p)$ goes the wrong way. (If an upper bound were valid, why not just bound it above by $1$?)

Comment: Oh you right, we want to prove $\prod_{2<p<z} \left(1-\frac{2}{p}\right) > \cdots$ to use it in the original proof don't we, oops. Editing

Comment: Still not right unfortunately: $\prod_{p<z} (1-\frac1p) \gg \frac1{\log z}$, not $1+\frac1{\log z}$. It might be worth including the details of how this piece of the computation ties in with the other pieces in the OP's question.

Comment: @GregMartin I originally wrote $\frac{1}{\log z}$ but then I edited my own answer to the wrong one... I even have the correct version on paper. Oops! Thanks a lot

Comment: @GregMartin Okay I think I got it correct this time, also elaborated on the gap from my answer to OP's question. Do you mind checking for me? hahaha

Comment: Thanks @GarethMa for the explanation of 2, greatly appreciated. However, I'm a little confused for 1 still. Do we not have $(1-\frac{1}{p})^2 = 1-\frac{2}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} > 1-\frac{2}{p}$ and not the other way around?

Comment: @James2390 Ahhhhhhhh oh god let me think of another approach, give me a second. Though the result $\prod_{p < z} \left(1 - \frac{k}{p}\right) \sim \frac{c(k)}{(\log(z))^k}$ is quite famous, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741633/derivation-of-a-generalization-of-mertens-third-theorem) for example.

Comment: @James2390 whoops, I can take the blame for that one. We can rescue it by writing $\prod_{p<z} (1-\frac2p) = \prod_{p<z} (1-\frac1p)^2 \prod_{p<z} (1-\frac1{(p+1)^2})$ and noting that $\prod_{p} (1-\frac1{(p+1)^2})$ converges.

Comment: @GregMartin I think you mean $(p-1)^2$, but yes this seems good! Could you elaborate on the convergence of the product?

Comment: @James2390 Isn't it more like $\prod \left(1 - \frac{2}{p}\right) = \prod \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)^2 \cdot \left(1 - \frac{1}{(p - 1)^2}\right)$ and the second term product is the twin prime constant.

Comment: @GarethMa, yes that's what I meant. and thanks! I think everything has come together

Comment: @GarethMa, since you're also learning sieve theory and seem to be familiar with Murty and Cojocaru, I was wondering if you had any insight about this other question that I had https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4565916/consequence-of-bruns-sieve